# Android: ListView rounded corner hidden by list item

Tags: android, listview, rounded-corners

I have this Listview element:

```
<ListView
android:id="@+id/category_list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:background="@drawable/list_background" 
android:layout_marginTop="10sp" 
android:layout_marginLeft="10sp" 
android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"

android:listSelector="@drawable/list_item_background"           
android:cacheColorHint="#FFFFFF"            

android:clipToPadding="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"     
android:clickable="true"    
android:longClickable="true"

android:footerDividersEnabled="true"
android:headerDividersEnabled="true"
android:dividerHeight="1px"

/>
```

where list_background is:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
    <corners android:radius="10dp" /> 
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/> 
</shape>
```

The list view loads itself with the rounded corners, but then, the items of the list hide the round corners.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the Above ListView, the first row of the ListView doesn't remains rounded..can you point me the reason behind that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the solution to the problem.

I was using the `android:cacheColorHint` setting the same color as I wanted to have for the ListView background, this was leading to have the rounded corners to be hid when the list was scrolling and after the scroll.

So, setting it to "transparent" (`#0000`) solved the issue!

Comment: In the Above solution, the first row of the ListView doesn't remains rounded..can you point me the reason behind that ?

Comment: Actually it does for me. It would be useful to see your code to check if there is anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have to disable the single item's background in the list, make it transparent so that it doesn't overlay the list