# Rounded corner list view in android

Tags: android

I have a problem that I want to create a list view with rounded corners but I failed to achieve the same. Please suggest me for the right solution.

**CustomShape XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item>
      <shape>
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#ffbbbbbb" />
            <corners android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
        android:topRightRadius="20dp"
         />
      </shape>
</item>
<item android:top="1dp" android:left="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp">
     <shape >
           <solid android:color="#ffffffff" />
          <corners android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
        android:topRightRadius="20dp"
         />
     </shape>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

**main XML:**

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" android:layout_marginTop="120dip">

        <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/lv_homeScreen" android:cacheColorHint="@color/WHITE" android:dividerHeight="0dp" android:background="@drawable/customshape">

        </ListView>


    </LinearLayout>
```

I have attached the code which I am using for the same desire. Please have a look and share me if there are any flaws.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at this one: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125185/android-listview-rounded-corner-hidden-by-list-item

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set this container.xml (in drawable) as the background of your listview:

```
<gradient
    android:startColor="#FFF"
    android:centerColor="#FFF"
    android:endColor="#FFFF"
    android:angle="270"/>

<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#e98d59"/>

<corners
    android:radius="10dp"/>
```